# Syntax error with hash argument and Hash#merge in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was trying to do an open source contribution, and the line of code in the star_rating method below with `options.merge()` (this is the change I tried to submit) was kicked back with the following message "This is invalid Ruby syntax (in both 1.8.7 and 1.9.3)..."  My question is why?  I checked the `Hash#merge` method on the ruby interactive shell and it seems to work.

```
def star_rating(options = {})
   ##original line of code
   has_many :rates_without_dimension, :as => :rateable, :class_name => 'RateMe', :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil}  

  ##line of code I tried to submit
  has_many :rates_without_dimension, :as => :rateable, options.merge(:class_name => 'RateMe'), :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil}  
end
```

Comment: Bruce, did you check whether this specific code would compile before submitting your change?

Comment: @philosodad, honestly, I wasn't sure how to do that (i.e, run the ruby interpreter on it)?? since this is part of a ruby/rails gem and I'm still trying to develop expertise at this.

Comment: Odds are that the repository for the gem has a testing framework of some kind attached to it. Try a `Rake -T` at the top level of the code repo to find all the rake tasks. There's probably a rake:test set of tasks. Running those will test your compiler. Of course, loading the file itself into irb would at least check if it compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed invalid syntax. The last arguments of a method call can be a Hash, in which case Ruby allows you to drop the enclosing `{}`:

```
foo(1, 2, 3, :a => 4, :b => 5)
# equivalent to:
foo(1, 2, 3, {:a => 4, :b => 5})
```

In your case, you have `:as => :rateable` before a simple argument (`options.merge`), that's not allowed.

If you inverted them, you still wouldn't get the effect you want:

```
has_many :rates_without_dimension, options.merge(:class_name => 'RateMe'), :as => :rateable, :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil}
# same as
has_many :rates_without_dimension, options.merge(:class_name => 'RateMe'), {:as => :rateable, :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil}}
# => has 3 arguments, not 2.
```

What you can do here is insure you are passing two parameters. One way to do this:

```
has_many :rates_without_dimension, options.merge(:class_name => 'RateMe', :as => :rateable, :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil})
```

Note that in Ruby 2.0, **it will be possible** to do what you wanted using the equivalent of the splat operators for arrays (`*`) which [will be `**` for hashes](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5474):

```
h = {:b => 2}
foo(:a => 1, **h, :c => 3)
# same as
foo(:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3) 

# so you will be allowed to write:
has_many :rates_without_dimension, :as => :rateable, **options.merge(:class_name => 'RateMe'), :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil}
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that he would be passing a hash literal in an argument list with no parentheses, which will not compile.

Comment: @MarcAndreLafortune Actually, I just tried this in irb and if the hash is the last argument, it does compile. My bad.

Comment: @philosodad: It does compile. It's only in the case when there is a single argument that is a Hash that it won't, as it will be interpreted as a block. `foo 1, {:a => 2}` is correct Ruby syntax.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: thanks, I ended up writing: `options[:class_name]||='Rate'
has_many :rates_without_dimension, :as => :rateable, :class_name=>options[:class_name], :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil}`

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: Thank you, because `options.merge(:class_name => 'RateMe', :as => :rateable, :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil})` was the other solution that would have worked I think.

Comment: @Bruce: it wasn't clear from your question that you wanted only the `:class_name` options. You could simply write `..., :class_name => options[:class_name] || 'RateMe', ...` then.

Answer (score 2):

According to chapter 6.4.4 of the first edition of "The Ruby Programming Language"

> Ruby allows you to omit the curly braces around the hash literal if it is the last argument to the method (or if the only argument that follows it is a block argument, prefixed with a &)

Your method call is of the form `method a => b, c => d, {e => f, g => h}, i => j`, because the hash.merge will return a hash. So you're breaking up the hash, rather than putting in a single hash, and the compiler assumes that `a => b, c=>d` is one hash, which would then not be the last argument, breaking the last argument rule.

Also, according to the same section

> If you omit the parentheses, then you *must* omit the curly braces.

Your hash.merge returns a hash in curly braces, which breaks that rule.

Edit: This would actually be fine as long as the hash is not the only argument.

Comment: "Your hash.merge returns a hash in curly braces, which breaks that rule." Thanks, spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, passing `options` into a Ruby method is usually done by making it the last parameter. In some cases, it's actually required to be the last parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin....Are conventions like this enumerated in the docs?  Or is it something one just picks up over time?

Comment: This answer is not correct--there is a specific reason why this code will fail to compile, it's compilation, not convention.

Comment: I realize there is a specific reason, as @philosodad points out, that this is required. Unfortunately I typed this while I was on a train and my WIFI cut out while I was researching it so I wasn't able to edit/complete my answer -- so my answer is not as correct as his.